# Possible discrepancy between two forms of the derivative of $|x|^{3/2}$?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

I've come across what seems to be a discrepancy between two different ways of representing the derivative of the function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by $f(x)=|x|^{3/2}$. I started by using the definition of the absolute value function:

$$
f(x) = |x|^{3/2} =
\begin{cases}
x^{3/2}, & x\geq 0 \\
(-x)^{3/2}, & x<0 \\
\end{cases}.
$$

Then using the chain rule, we have

$$
f'(x) = 
\begin{cases}
\frac{3}{2}x^{1/2}, & x>0 \\
-\frac{3}{2}(-x)^{1/2}, & x<0 \\
\end{cases}.
$$

Based on the graph of the function, it seemed reasonable to check if the derivative existed at zero. Thus I made the following computations:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
f_+'(0)&=\lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^+}\frac{h^{3/2}}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0^+}h^{1/2}=0 \\
f_-'(0)&=\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h} = \lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{(-h)^{3/2}}{h}=-\lim_{h\to 0^-}\frac{(-h)^{3/2}}{(-h)}=-\lim_{h\to 0^-}(-h)^{1/2}=0.
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

From this, it seems that the derivative exists at $x=0$ and that $f'(0)=0$. However, if we find the derivative using the chain rule and the fact that we can write the derivative of the absolute value function as

$$
\frac{d}{dx}\left[\,|x|\,\right ]=\frac{x}{|x|},
$$

we obtain

$$
f'(x)=\frac{3}{2}|x|^{1/2}\cdot \frac{x}{|x|} = \frac{3x}{2\sqrt{|x|}},
$$

which should be undefined at $x=0$. So the question is, should the derivative be defined at $0$ or should it not? If so, is this just an issue with the notation we use for the derivative of the absolute value function or a sign error or something? Thanks for any input.

Comment: Your $f$ is differentiable at $0$.

Comment: It is the same derivative. Where $x\geq 0$, the x in the numerator of your last expression simplifies with the $\sqrt{x}$ . For the negative part, multiply the numerator by $(-1)(-1)$ and get $\frac{-3}{2}\frac{-x}{\sqrt{-x}}$, which again simplifies

Comment: You cannot apply chain rule with the absolute value of $x$ inside a function.

Comment: @dmtri Why not?

Comment: @dirtydivider, because the function abs$(x)$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We have

- for $x>0$

$$f'(x)= \frac{3x}{2\sqrt{|x|}}=\frac{3x}{2\sqrt{x}}=\frac32\sqrt x$$

- for $x<0$

$$f'(x)= \frac{3x}{2\sqrt{|x|}}=-\frac{3|x|}{2\sqrt{|x|}}=-\frac32\sqrt {|x|}$$

which agrees with your initial evaluation.

Therefore since $f(x)$ is continuos and

$$\lim_{x\to 0^+} f'(x)=\lim_{x\to 0^-} f'(x)=0$$

we have that $f'(0)=0$ according to what you have already found directly from the definition.

Refer also to the related: [Suppose $f(x)$ exists for all $x\neq0$, and $\lim_{x\rightarrow0}f'(x)$ exists. Show that $f'(0)$ exists.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118564/505767)

Comment: These only say what happens when $x\neq 0$. From this and not what I wrote above how do you then conclude that $f'(0)=0$?

Comment: I’ve shown that your last derivation is equivalent to the first one (wasn’t that your doubt?) and from here we can also conclude that $f’(0)=0$ as you have shown, in a proper way, directly by the definition.

Comment: Ah yes. I suppose you are right. Thanks!

Comment: On the other hand, I guess my issue was that in writing it the second way, we have no way of recovering information about $f'(0)$, and I found that troubling.

Comment: @dirtydivider Yes we can, refer to [Related OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118564/505767)

Comment: @gimusi I was thinking that in the related question you put the link on in the  answer, why the first answer in that question was using L'Hospitals rule ? like how do we know that the limit is of indeterminate form, like is it because we do not know what is f(0)? is it indeterminate or does not exist? I think it says that $f$ exists for all $x \neq 0$ but still we do not know whether $f(x)$ exist or not at $x=0$?

Answer (score 3):

We have $|\frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}|=\sqrt{|x|} \to 0$ as $x \to 0$. Hence $f$ is differentiable at $0$ anf $f'(0)=0$.

Comment: It seems that this result was alreary obtained by the OP. Take a look to the second part.

Comment: Simply and neat done!  +1

Answer (score 2):

Your basic error comes from the line where you derive the norm $|\cdot |$ which is not differentiable at $0$. Hence, what you write holds for $x\neq 0$ and you can not conclude like this. The previous calculations are totally okay (and if needed you can shorten then as Fred did in his answer).

Comment: Why not? $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\,|x|\,\right ]=\frac{x}{|x|}$ is true for $x\neq 0$.

Comment: Note that the result by the definition was already obtained by the OP. His doubt was about a "possible discrepancy" obtained using chain rule and $\frac{d}{dx}\left[\,|x|\,\right ]=\frac{x}{|x|}$.

Answer (score 1):

Gimusi 's link addresses the problem.

This answer also uses the MVT.

$f(x)$ is continuos in $\mathbb{R}$.

$f'(x)$ exists in $\mathbb{R}$ \ {$0$}.,

and

$\lim_{ x \rightarrow 0^+}f'(x)=$

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^-}f'(x)=:L$

Show that $f'(0)$ exists and

$f'(0) =L$.

MVT:

Let $x >0:$

$\dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x} = f'(t)$, $t \in (0,x)$.

$\lim_{x \rightarrow 0^+} \dfrac{f(x)-f(0)}{x}=$

$\lim_{t \rightarrow 0^+}f'(t)=L$.

Similarly for $x <0$, and $x \rightarrow 0^-.$

Hence $f'(0)$ exists and $f'(0)=L$.

Comment: Very nice alternative proof!

Comment: Gimusi.Thanks, interesting problem..

Answer (score 0):

You can't use the chain rule because

$$|x|'=\frac{x}{|x|}$$ is undefined at $x=0$.

That doesn't mean that the derivative of $|x|^{3/2}$ is undefined, just that you cannot conclude using the chain rule.

---

The correct way is from the definition of the derivative,

$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{|x|^{3/2}-0}{x}=\pm\lim_{x\to0}|x|^{1/2}=0.$$

(The $\pm$ choice depends on the sign of $x$, but it doesn't matter.)

Comment: We can use chain rule separetely for $x>0$ and $x<0$ and from here conclude that $f'(0)=0$. I can agree with you that the evaluation by the definition is preferable but both ways are correct.