# Why $\frac{M}{2}|\tau|^{1/2}sign(\tau) = \frac{1} {2}\lambda \Leftrightarrow \tau(\lambda) = \frac{4\lambda |\lambda|}{M^2}$

Tags: linear-algebra

I want to minimize the function

$$f(\tau) = \frac{M}{6}|\tau|^{3/2} -\frac{\lambda}{2}\tau \tag{1}, \quad \tau,\lambda \in \mathbb{R},$$

with respect to the varable $\tau$. To do so, I took the derivative

$$\partial_{\tau} f(\tau) =\frac{M}{4}|\tau|^{1/2}sign(\tau)- \frac{\lambda}{2}\tag{2}$$ and set it to zero to get

$$\frac{M}{4}|\tau|^{1/2}sign(\tau) = \frac{\lambda}{2} \tag{3}$$

I compute the derivative based on this [link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2928624/possible-discrepancy-between-two-forms-of-the-derivative-of-x3-2?rq=1). In the textbook I am reading it is stated

> [image]

I Could not find out how from $(3)$ we get

$$\tau(\lambda) = \frac{4\lambda |\lambda|}{M^2} \tag{4}$$

Could you please someone help to prove it?

Comment: That's not true if $\lambda=M=0$, or $\lambda=1, M=-1$ for example. What is the *full* context of the question, what have you tried, and where did you get stuck?

Comment: @dxiv I did some refactoring in my post. Here is a the [page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZxI0.png) of the textbook where I isolated the function $f(\tau)$. I will remove the link in some point. I hope now to get some respond in my question now.

Comment: That's assuming $\,M \gt 0\,$ which is not stated in the problem. If that's the case, note that $\,|a|\,\text{sign}(b)=c \iff |a|=|c| \;\;and\;\; \text{sign}(b)=\text{sign(c)}\,$. Then eq. $(3)$ gives $\,\text{sign}(\tau)=\text{sign}(\lambda)\,$ and $\,|\tau|=4 \lambda^2 / M^2\,$. Finally, $\,\lambda^2 \,\text{sign}(\lambda)=\lambda\,|\lambda|\,$.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I think I got each the points, but how do we get $(4)$ combining  $|\tau|=4 \lambda^2 / M^2$ and $\lambda^2 \,\text{sign}(\lambda)=\lambda\,|\lambda| $? Could you please give some more detail? It would also be great if you give it as an answer in order to close the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming $\,M \gt 0\,$, and using that $\,a = b \iff |a| = |b| \;\;and\;\; \text{sign}(a) = \text{sign}(b)\,$:

$$
\frac{M}{4}|\tau|^{1/2}\,\text{sign}(\tau) = \frac{\lambda}{2} \;\;\;\;\iff\;\;\;\;
\begin{cases}
\text{sign}(\tau) &= \text{sign}\left(\frac{2\lambda}{M}\right) = \text{sign}(\lambda)
\\ |\tau| &= \frac{4\lambda^2}{M^2}
\end{cases}
$$

Combining the two, and using that $\,a = |a|\,\text{sign}(a)\,$ and $|a| = a\,\text{sign}(a)\,$:

$$
\tau = |\tau|\,\text{sign}(\tau) = \frac{4\lambda^2\,\text{sign}(\lambda)}{M^2} = \frac{4\lambda\left(\lambda\,\text{sign}(\lambda)\right)\,}{M^2} = \frac{4 \lambda\,|\lambda|}{M^2}
$$

Comment: Thanks, now it is clear.