# Show that $f’(0)$ exists and equals 1.

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

Let $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continous. Assume that $f’(x)$ exists for all $x \neq 0$ and $ \lim_{x\to\ 0} f'(x) = 1$. Show that $f’(0)$ exists and $f’(0) = 1$

My attempt:
$$1 = \lim_{x\to0} \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h} = \lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(0 + h) - f(0)}{h} = f’(0)$$

I don’t think that the limit interchange that I have done is correct. Can someone help me out with how to do this.

Comment: Are you sure this is true? Consider $f(x) = |x| + 1$, then $f'(x)$ exists for all $x \to 0$ and $\lim_{x \to 0} f(x) = 1$, but $f$ is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer really sorry, that was a typo, I have added an edit

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove that $f'(a)=\lim_{x\rightarrow a}f'(x)$.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/257907/prove-that-fa-lim-x-rightarrow-afx)

Comment: Another one: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/53065/42969.

Comment: Also this: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1118564/42969

Comment: @MartinR I’m checking, thanks a lot for these.

Comment: X^2+1 is a function such that f(0)=1 Bit f‘(0)=0. your Statement is wrong

Comment: @miracle173 in this $\lim_{\x\to 0} f’ \neq 1$

Comment: @user601297. thank you. I misread your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the post Martin R linked says something similar, but this is a standard application of the MVT: Fix $h>0$ and consider $\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h}$, then by the mean value theorem you can find a point $a \in (0,h)$ such that $\frac{f(h) - f(0)}{h} = f'(a)$. Now take $h \to 0$. What happens to $a$? Keep in mind that $a$ depends on $h$.

Also, interchanging limits is not a good idea unless you're appealing to a specific theorem/result that lets you do this. In general even "easy" limits can't be changed.

Comment: When you ask me what happens to $a$ ( continuity if $f’$) are you suggesting that $f’$ is continous? Because that’s not given in the question.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't read that. You don't need continuity. I've edited my answer -- it's almost the same. The idea is that as $h \to 0$, $a \to 0$ so the RHS goes to $1$ and hence the LHS goes to $1$ (and exists).

Comment: Yes i got it, thanks a lot